# Is the map $ \varphi: \mathbb{A}^1-\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^2, x \mapsto\left(\frac{1}{x}, \frac{1}{x^3}\right) $ a dominant rational map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to show this is a dominant rational map where our field is some arbitrary algebraically closed field (with reasonable characteristic) :

$$
\varphi: \mathbb{A}^1-\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^2, x \mapsto\left(\frac{1}{x}, \frac{1}{x^3}\right)
$$

So if we were working with complex numbers, this would be easy since we can show the zero set of any polynomials that vanish at the points $(x, x^3)$ is just the zero polynomial which can be argued by taking the integers and taking the limit. But the problem here is that since we are working on an arbitrary field, we cannot use any ordering argument. So how can we argue that this is a dominant map.

(Note that this may not actually be a dominant map, but I strongly suspect it is)

Comment: This map is never dominant over any field: the image is contained in the proper closed subset $V(y-x^3)$ over any field. Your argument in the complex case is flawed too.

Comment: In particular, there is a dominant map $V$ to $W$ only if $\dim(V)\ge\dim(W)$.

Comment: Thank you, i will rename the question